# When is the earliest a US university will create an official transcript?

Tags: united-states, transcript-of-records

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/104691/listed-school-on-interview-but-not-on-application) about not supplying a transcript from a university they just started attending in an application to a different graduate school got me thinking. At what stage of being a student will a US university generate an official transcript.

When is the earliest I can get an official transcript:

After being admitted, but prior to registering for classes?

After registering for classes, but prior to starting classes?

After the start of classes, but prior to full refund drop date?

Some other time?

Presumably this information is buried in some webpage of the university registrars office.

Comment: Are you asking about official transcripts specifically? My recollection of campus software I used as an undergraduate is that unofficial transcripts could be easily produced at any stage as long as you had an active university account, which would be somewhere between admission and registration.

Comment: @BryanKrause yeah the official fancy one (see edit).

Comment: Is there any particular reason you could not ask your registrar this question?  (Horse's mouth, and all that....)